# empathy resets my google account after restart

Tags: empathy

I currently work on a Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin. There is a small annoyance with Empathy though. Every time i log out, empathy just resets my google talk account settings, so i have to login after every time. Is there a way or setting to handle this small problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps:

1. Close Empathy (completely exit)
2. Open "Passwords and Encryption Keys", a.k.a. Seahorse
3. Delete the stored passwords for my Gtalk account. For some reason there were two entries, one of which had the current password and the other had the old password. Neither was editable; you should view and delete them.
4. Close Seahorse and reopen Empathy
5. Enter your password in Empathy when asked

Comment: i have done it, after restarting my system i will check it out, thanks ; )

Comment: it is still the same, have moved to pidgin eventually.

Comment: However you could find workarounds for that, it seems to be a bug. I suggest to report it!